# ibatis query gives many results but only one is needed

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, ibatis

I am optimizing database usage on ibatis SQL queries. I have a situation where the query results many entries but only one of them is needed. `QueryForList` gives too much extra information through the slow connection and `QueryForObject`is not working if result is not unique. How I should do this?

I don't wanna use the `list.get(0)` with `QueryForList`if I just can omit transfering the unnecessary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit result set to only one row by adding 'LIMIT 1' to your sql query.